# GKE monitoring, understanding Evictable and Non Evictable memory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have here a graph of my memory limit utilization. I understand that non-evictable cannot be reclaimed and evictable can be reclaimed. Given I have non-evictable usage that goes over my limit, but have enough reclaimable memory. Do I just get the mean and that will be my utilization?

[image]

Comment: As you can read [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_kubernetes), _"memory_type: Either `evictable` or `non-evictable`. Evictable memory is memory that can be easily reclaimed by the kernel, while non-evictable memory cannot."_

Comment: @mario so you're saying that evictable means reclaimable. What does reclaimable mean? How would the kernel tell if a particular memory address is evictable/reclaimable or not?

Comment: @Robino if you're still looking for a solution to the original question, I just posted an answer that might be of help.

Comment: @AkashAgarwal I read the original question to be asking asking about evictable vs non-evictable memory, for example in a container. Your answer doesn't seem to touch on whether memory is evictable or non-evictable and is specific only to nodes. For me, I am still in the dark as to the understanding of evictable/reclaimable memory.

Comment: @Robino Gotcha—yes, I'm in the dark about this too. May I ask what is your use-case for developing this understanding?

Comment: @AkashAgarwal I am usually motivated by little more than an insatiable thirst for knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late to the party but what I ended up doing in a similar confusion is this:

1. I used the metric `node/memory/allocatable_utilization`,
2. filtered by `cluster_name` (this could be anything you want really),
3. group by `node_name`,
4. aggregated by `sum`,
5. and finally set the threshold to not be above for **all the timelines**.

This means that if all my nodes' allocatable RAM utilization was above 90%, it means that the whole cluster's RAM utilization is above 90%, which is exactly what I wanted to track. :)

For `node/cpu/allocatable_utilization`, you'd wanna skip step 3 and 4, because there is no concept of `evictable` or `non-evictable` CPU.